# How to ignore DST when parsing string to time (Time.parse) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, utc, dst, datetime-parsing

I need to parse strings with timestamps and convert them to `Time` objects.

I am struggling to understand how `Time.parse` works and how to ignore DST and use always `UTC` or simply convert to `UTC`

I keep having duplicate hours when time transition from `GMT` to `DST`. I have tried:

- `Time.parse(t)`
- `Time.parse(t).utc`
- `Time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

and all give the same result.This is an extract of my code

```
require 'time'
ts = ["2010-03-28 00:00:00", "2010-03-28 01:00:00", "2010-03-28 02:00:00", "2010-03-28 03:00:00"]

ts.each do |t|
  puts "t: #{t} -- pt: #{Time.parse(t)} -- dst: #{Time.parse(t).dst?} -- utc: #{Time.parse(t).utc} -- strptime: #{Time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}"
end
```

The output is:

```
t: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 -- pt: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 +0000 -- dst: false -- utc: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 UTC -- strptime: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 +0000
t: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 -- pt: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100 -- dst: true -- utc: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 UTC -- strptime: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100
t: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 -- pt: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100 -- dst: true -- utc: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 UTC -- strptime: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100
t: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 -- pt: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 +0100 -- dst: true -- utc: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 UTC -- strptime: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 +0100
```

Location: UK (if `locale` is important)

Time: `DST`

`Ruby 2.0.0-p247` on `macos` (I cannot change it)

**EDIT**

Not sure this is a hack, but adding `" UTC"` to the time string solves the problem. See updated code:

```
require 'time'
ts.map{|t| t + " UTC"}.each do |t|
  puts "t: #{t} -- pt: #{Time.parse(t)} -- dst: #{Time.parse(t).dst?} -- utc: #{Time.parse(t).utc} -- \
  strptime: #{Time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}"
end
```

The output is now:

```
t: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 UTC -- pt: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 UTC -- dst: false -- utc: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 UTC --   strptime: 2010-03-28 00:00:00 +0000
t: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 UTC -- pt: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 UTC -- dst: false -- utc: 2010-03-28 01:00:00 UTC --   strptime: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100
t: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 UTC -- pt: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 UTC -- dst: false -- utc: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 UTC --   strptime: 2010-03-28 02:00:00 +0100
t: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 UTC -- pt: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 UTC -- dst: false -- utc: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 UTC --   strptime: 2010-03-28 03:00:00 +0100
```

Of course the last parsing with `strptime` is wrong as it is ignoring `UTC`.